# Readonly std::map?

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary

I would like to return from my class an read-only adapter something like `boost::iterator_range`, but for a `std::map` and support for `operator[]` (i.e. not `boost::iterator_range<std::pair<key_type, value_type>>`) does something like that exists?

e.g.

```
class processor
{
public:

   // boost::map_view is made up.
   // The data member could be std::map boost::multimap etc...

    virtual boost::map_view<std::string, boost::signals2::signal<int>> outputs() = 0;

};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use constant reference.

Comment: I had that as a comment, but I deleted it as, given the context, I think the OP seems to know what they are doing enough that they would have thought of that and ruled it out, although they didn't make it entirely clear why. I suppose sometimes you just don't think of the really simple solution.

Comment: Good point. I didn't give the whole context. The implementation will not always use std::map as the data container.

Comment: Thanks.I too believe in just giving idea and let them come up with the solution.

Comment: @ronag So why not return a `const` reference to whatever data container the implementation uses?  You can abstract it away via `typedef`, templatization, or a wrapper class if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a simple class that wraps boost::iterator_range and has const reference to your map as a member. Your operator[] implementation should check if passed key is within range by calling map comparison object on first and last range element(note, that it is not sufficient for multi_map) and if it is just call underlying map[].